# Is there a way to extract a formula result from a formula to do further math on it?

Tags: excel, formula

This function formula looks in the specified filepath in cell A2 and returns the filename based on the file extension in cell B2:

Formula in Cell  A4 :           `=IFERROR(INDEX(GetFileNamesbyExt($A$2,$B$2),ROW()-2),"")`

Result Cell A4 :                **Servicing Balance Allocation Report 1-13-2020.xlsx**

The problem though is, I need to be able to extract the number 13 in the above Result so I can do math with it.   Problem I run into is that *since the result is a formula result, I can't seem to extract the day portion.*

I don't mind if someone has a VBA solution, whatever works.

The goal is to be able to get the number of days difference between the two most recent files based on the date in the file string.
For example:

Difference between:

Servicing Balance Allocation Report 1-13-2020.xlsx

Servicing Balance Allocation Report 1-17-2020.xlsx

```
= 4
```

Comment: Sure, using `MID`, if the filenames all end in the date. Or if the only dashes in the filename are the ones in the date portion.

Comment: What happens if the month is different, say if its' `Servicing Balance Allocation Report 2-17-2020.xlsx`?

Comment: @ORLANDOVAZQUEZ it does not matter that the cell has a formula, other formula will refer to the output and not the formula.

Comment: Actually, you are correct.  Mid works.
=MID(A6,39,2)  = 13

Comment: @bigben  Actually, you are correct. Mid works. =MID(A6,39,2) = 13     thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
=LEFT(MID(A4,FIND("-",A4)+1,999),FIND("-",MID(A4,FIND("-",A4)+1,999))-1)
```

basically getting the text between the dashes.

**NOTE:**

It is easier to see in two cells.  Say in **D1** put:

```
=MID(A4,FIND("-",A4)+1,999)
```

and in **E1** put:

```
=LEFT(D1,FIND("-",D1)-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the day use:

```
=DAY(--TRIM(LEFT(MID(A4,SEARCH("??-*-????.",A4),999),FIND(".",MID(A4,SEARCH("??-*-????.",A4),999))-1)))
```

to get the days between we can drop the DAY() and just subtract the dates:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(MID(A5,SEARCH("??-*-????.",A5),999),FIND(".",MID(A5,SEARCH("??-*-????.",A5),999))-1))-TRIM(LEFT(MID(A4,SEARCH("??-*-????.",A4),999),FIND(".",MID(A4,SEARCH("??-*-????.",A4),999))-1))
```

[image]

Comment: @scott craner   I'd like to use above but it generates #Value error

Comment: I believe I'll add a mid and find combo so as to extract day portion.  Thanks all!